# Delete Old Records on Entity Framework's db.BulkInsert()

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I have a table that stores the favourite fruit of my users:

```
CREATE TABLE UserFavouriteFruit (ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Username varchar(20), Fruit nvarchar(20), IsDisabled bit DEFAULT(0));

INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Peter', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Peter', 'Pear');
INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Peter', 'Orange');
INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Paul', 'Water Melon');
INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Paul', 'Banana');
INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Lucy', 'Apple');
INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Lucy', 'Blueberry');
INSERT INTO UserFavouriteFruit (Username, Fruit) VALUES ('Mary', 'Strawberry');
```

I have a console application that calls a third party API to get updated favourite fruits of some existing and some new users. Some had the same selections and some would be different. When this application calls Entity Framework's db.BulkInsert(), all new data are inserted into our SQL Azure database.

Would you please let me know how I could set up the mechanism so that when I insert the new entries, the relevant users' old entries will have the IsDisabled field set to 1?

Thanks,
WY

Comment: Why keep the old values? Why not UPDATE?

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` is what you need. Native EF doesn't support this feature by default.

There's an extension that can help you with this http://www.zzzprojects.com/entity-framework/library/bulk-merge (not free).

If you want to keep it free, you can use string builder to build the T-SQL command that will do the merging or create a stored procedure that does `MERGE` and pass the dataset thru user defined type. I will suggest to go to stored procedure route because it's straight forward and most importantly it's FREE. :)